# How to split column names attributes and length separate using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to split oracle table column names,attributes and length separately for to prepare Data sheet. Currently I am doing manual by copying into Note pad and doing split. This is good for small tables but for large columns it is taking more time. Is it any way do program or in SQL query itself.Please help on this.

For eg:

```
Column  attribute
A       varchar2(25)
B       Number(13,2)
C       Number(20)
d       varchar2(25)
e       varchar2(25)
```

I want separate as

```
 A    varchar2   25
 B    Number     13,2
 C    Number     20
 d    varchar2   25
 E    varchar2   25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to data dictionary, you may use :

```
select COLUMN_NAME  ,DATA_TYPE ,  TRIM ( BOTH ',' FROM DATA_LENGTH||','||DATA_PRECISION) 
       as length_precision
FROM user_tab_columns where table_name='YOURTABLE';
```

Comment: your query worked for me I have access to data dictionary  how to get the count also in your query.please help.

Answer (score 0):

how about using USER_TAB_COLS instead?

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision
  FROM user_tab_cols
 ORDER BY table_name, column_id
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Is it possible to get the count along with above query

Comment: @userAnalyst Do you want to count the number of columns per table? Yes you can, you can add COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY table_name) column_cnt in the SELECT clause.